# The number of representations of a positive integer n as the sum of the product of two positive integers.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, combinations

I'm looking for the function **$f(n)$** that calculates the **number of representations** of a positive integer $n$ as the exact sum of the product of two positive integers. I'm not familiar with this research field so I wonder if it is well known.

For better illustration, here are some examples:

**$f(1)=1$**, because there is only one such representation {1$\times$1};

**$f(2)=3$**, because there are three representations {1$\times$1+1$\times$1, 1$\times$2, 2$\times$1};

**$f(3)=5$**, because {1$\times$1+1$\times$1+1$\times$1, 1$\times$2+1$\times$1, 2$\times$1+1$\times$1, 1$\times$3, 3$\times$1};

**$f(4)=11$**, because {1$\times$1+1$\times$1+1$\times$1+1$\times$1, 1$\times$2+1$\times$1+1$\times$1, 2$\times$1+1$\times$1+1$\times$1, 1$\times$2+1$\times$2, 1$\times$2+2$\times$1, 2$\times$1+2$\times$2, 1$\times$3+1$\times$1, 3$\times$1+1$\times$1, 1$\times$4, 2$\times$2,  4$\times$1};

**$f(5)=17$**;

**$f(6)=34$**;

$\vdots$

The question is **$f(n)=?$**

Note:

(i) 1$\times$2 and 2$\times$1 are regarded as two different representations;

(ii) 1$\times$2+2$\times$1 and 2$\times$1+1$\times$2 are regarded as the same representation.

Comment: Is this the same as the sequence [A006171](https://oeis.org/A006171) at OEIS? Can you compute $f(6)$?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde  OK. Let me check.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde $f(6)=34$. It's the same as A006171! Thank you so much for sharing.

Comment: Before being convinced that the sequences coincide, you should calculate some more values , unless it can be seen anyway that the given OEIS-link is the desired one.

Comment: After I compute $f(6)=34$,  the sequence 1，3，5，11，17，34 only corresponds to A006171.